# Comment Instagram Post Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to comment on Instagram posts.

But my code doesn't work and I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.79)

```
comment_box = self.driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    "//textarea[@placeholder='Add a comment…']"
)

# comment_box.click()
# comment_box.clear()
comment_box.send_keys("Message")
```